# Is int & foo(); an lvalue?

Tags: c++, function, lvalue

I know there might be other similar questions but they didn't quite answer my question.

I've been browsing through some slides from a lecture about `C++` type deduction and on one of them I found the following statement:

```
int & foo();           // foo() is lvalue;
```

At first, I thought it was just wrong - `foo` is a function, it can't be assigned to, it's not an lvalue. But now I'm thinking the author might have had something different in mind. Namely, that a **function call** might be an lvalue, not the fuction itself.

So in other words:

1. is `foo` an lvalue?
2. is `foo()` an lvalue?
3. can a fuction (**not a function call**) ever be assigned to (i.e. `foo = something;`)?
4. "lvalue is every object/thing that can be assigned to" - is this statement always correct and accurate?

Question `4` requires some more explanation. With it, I'm trying to understand what an lvalue really is. Another definition I've seen states: "lvalues have storage addresses that can be obtained". I'm not sure what **storage** address exactly is but taking our function `foo` as an example - we can definitely obtain **some** address of that fuction. In `C++` it's just the name of the function

```
foo;   // returns the address of funtion 'foo'
```

But at the same time I don't think we can ever assign to `foo` (question `3`). So - is it an lvalue or not?

I'd appreciate it if you answered all 4 points. I'm marking the question as `C++` and not `C++11` as I believe the question applies to all versions of the language. If there are any differences, however, please mention them.

Comment: You might be interested in taking a look through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: I upvoted because the question shows research effort, is useful and clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is `foo` an lvalue?

Yes. A primary expression that designates a function is an *lvalue*. However, in some contexts, the function is implicitly converted to a pointer; that pointer is a *prvalue* (or just an *rvalue*, before C++11).

> is `foo()` an lvalue?

Yes. The value of a function call is an *lvalue* if the result is an *lvalue* reference type, as it is here.

> can a fuction (not a function call) ever be assigned to

No. Only modifiable objects can be assigned to.

> "lvalue is every object/thing that can be assigned to" - is this statement always correct and accurate?

No. An *lvalue* is an expression that designates a function or object. It can only be assigned to if it designates a modifiable object.